# Multiple steps with independant readers

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring-batch job with two steps.
Everything is configured in a Config Java class like that:

```
class MyConfigClass {
    @Bean(name = "readerA")
    public ItemReader<ResponseObject> readerA(Environment environment, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return new ReaderA();
    }

    @Bean(name = "readerB")
    public ItemReader<ResponseObject> readerB(Environment environment, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return new ReaderB();
    }

    //Processor
    //...

    //Writer
    //...

    @Bean
    Step stepA(@Qualifier("readerA") ItemReader<ResponseObject> readerA,
                         ...) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA")
                .<ResponseObject, ResponseObject>chunk(1)
                .reader(readerA)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Step stepB(@Qualifier("readerB") ItemReader<ResponseObject> readerB,
                         ...) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepB")
                .<ResponseObject, ResponseObject>chunk(1)
                .reader(readerB)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                       @Qualifier("stepA") Step stepA,
                       @Qualifier("stepB") Step stepB){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepA)
                .next(stepB)
                .build();
    }
```

But I see it initialize readerA twice. Debug mode goes twice in readerA() and once in stepA() and once in stepB().

Comment: it's not clear whats problem you are getting ?

Comment: The problem is when StepB is processing, ReaderA is used instead of ReaderB.

Comment: My problem was ReaderA never finished. Relative to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094565/spring-batch-job-does-not-end-after-last-step