# Spring-Batch job does not end after last step

Tags: java, spring-batch

My Spring-Batch job is set like that:

```
@Bean
Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                   @Qualifier("stepA") Step stepA,
                   @Qualifier("s"tepB) Step stepB) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepA)
            .next(stepB)
            .build();
}
```

And here is my launcher:

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher(@Qualifier("myJob") Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.job = job;
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
void launcher() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    jobLauncher.run(job, newExecution());
}

private JobParameters newExecution() {
    Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    this.dateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    this.dateTimeString = this.dateTime.toString(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime());
    JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(this.dateTimeString);
    parameters.put("currentTime", parameter);

    return new JobParameters(parameters);
}
```

As you can see, my job is scheduled to launch every 5 seconds.
But, after first launch, it does not end; it goes on the next execution.
The job is like in a loop. I would like it to stop and restart after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I missed that readers need to return null when they finish. Problem solved.

Comment: If you are using Tasklet and still the issue persists?

Answer (score -3):

You can also use System.exit(0); at the end of main class which will terminate JVM resulting in terminatation of batch.

Comment: This is not recommended.

Comment: this not recommended and not working